# Problems with slqlite's begintransaction through different activities

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-4.4-kitkat, start-activity

I'm having a problem with Kitkat. I've an app that was working (in fact it works in android 2.3-4.2) but now behaves strangely in Kitkat.
When I call

```
 db.beginTransaction();
 Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),TriggerSelectionPopupActivity.class);
 intent.putExtra("_id", _id);
 startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

when the `TriggerSelectionPopupActivity` returns the caller activity is stuck (`onActivityResult` is not called either).
This happens also if the call is a normal `startActivity` while doesn't happen if I don't call the `beginTransaction()` method on the database.

No error message are generated, BTW, just the ANR situation.

Does anyone have experienced a similar problem?

**Update**

Ok, I figured out that it was due to the  "don't keep activities" option in developer options. When the `TriggerSelectionPopupActivity` returned couldn't find the caller activity. Thus, it was re-created and `db.beginTransaction()` was called again causing the deadlock.

Comment: I have no idea why you think what you are doing is sensible. This is equivalent to starting a database transaction when responding to one URL in a Web server and not closing it, expecting to commit or roll it back on some subsequent request.

Comment: I know, it is not clear to me either. I simply figured out that if I didn't use the  db.beginTransaction(); it did work.
However I just figured out that it was due to the "don't keep activity" option in developer options.